# Tag all stages of docker multi-stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to build and tag all stages of a multistage build? A verbose (and somewhat slow) workaround is to call `docker build` several times:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build
    --target builder
    --tag bdr
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build
    --target build
    --tag bd
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build
    --target runtime
    --tag rt
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build
    --target test
    --tag tst
```

EDIT: In my case every call to `docker build` includes ~2 seconds of overhead:

```
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 34B done
#1 DONE 0.6s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 DONE 0.7s

#3 [internal] load metadata for my_parent_image...
#3 DONE 0.7s

#4 [builder 1/6] FROM my_parent_image@s...
#4 DONE 0.0s
```

Comment: As far as I know that's how you do it. It shouldn't be too slow, though, later builds should reuse the earlier ones due to layer caching.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of [docker buildx bake](https://github.com/docker/buildx#buildx-bake-options-target) which is at last check still considered experimental and I haven't seen a lot of traction for the syntax from the community.

There's certainly been some discussion on adding this functionality in the [buildkit issues](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/98) and I'd recommend following those issues and adding your use case if you'd like to see it added.